# ping communication between interfaces in linux

Tags: linux, ip, routing, ping

Part 1 - Is it possible to ping between ip on port0 to ip on port1 of same NIC adapter ? The ICMP should traverse on the wire connected between ports. i.e

```
 On HOST A with two-port-adapter
 port-0-adapterA ---- ping-icmp-to ---- port-1-adapterA
```

Part 2 - Is it possible to ping between ip on port0(first-adapter) to ip on port0(second-adapter) on the SAME system ? Same ICMP should traverse on the wire connected between ports. i.e

```
 On SAME HOST A with two single-port-adapters
 port-0-adapterA ---- ping-icmp-to ---- port-0-adapterB
```

condition -

```
 ICMP should traverse physically on the wire connected between ports.
```

What kind of LINUX ip/route commands do we need to set to get this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Forcing Ping to Egress When Destination Interface is Local (Debian)](https://superuser.com/questions/1241712/forcing-ping-to-egress-when-destination-interface-is-local-debian)

Comment: I found a solution by (Steve Kehlet) at below link - https://serverfault.com/questions/127636/force-local-ip-traffic-to-an-external-interface

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it can be done with IP Tables or so on.

However, if you do not mind sending packets manualy, It can be done using the [Click Modular Router](https://github.com/kohler/click/wiki/FAQs-about-click). It allows you to send as well as receive any packets through any of the interfaces, process them and reply with any other packet.

`Note` : As expected, you need to have root access to be able to access the interfaces through click.