# Linux force packet to egress (and avoid local/kernel trafic)

Tags: linux, networking, python, iptables, network-adapter

0
down vote
favorite

I have a 20-ports switch connected to a 20-NICs PC (1-to-1) and want to load it with traffic. Of course configuring all NICs with different IPs and start my client/server (Python3) scripts (or iperf3) will generate local traffic only unless I force the traffic out through the NICs.

I found (here) the two main 'tricks' in order to achieve this:

**a.) Using network namespace:**

[+] It Will do exactly what I want by isolating (VM/docker-like) each NIC into a box

[+] Python3 seem to support netns (Pyroute2)

[-] Not sure how I can open a socket into a netns/python thread (10 threads x 2 (client/server) )

**b.) Using a ghost IP (iptable: S/D-NAT + pre/post-routing):**

[+] All NICs remain in the root network namespace (still get to collect data through psutil) and configure at global level

[+] Python TCP threaded script can run wihtout specific lib/support for netns

[-] In case of reconfiguration of my setup (IPs, VLAN,...), IPTable script must be adapted accordingly.

I would like to know if I overlook another possibility here and/or if for a.) I am getting it (all) wrong (since I can't find a decent example with a socket opened in a single Python script over different netns...)

Comment: Please don’t cross-post questions on multiple Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: Yeah, indeed, sorry about that: is there a way I can remove/delete the original (now duplicated) post on the other - and obviously wrong - stack exchange site ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the trouble is with using python in a network namespace - once you've moved the interface to the namespace, and started the python interpreter in it, you can just open a normal socket. As there's only a single NIC in the namespace, everything will get routed correctly.

I don't understand your second method, and I don't see why you'd need NAT.

The third method would be to set up each NIC with a different IP, keep them all in the root namespace, and have the applications *bind* to a specific socket. This is part of the normal socket API; I'd have to look up how Python supports it, but I'm sure it does. Alternatively, use something like `socat` to generate network traffic; it has options to bind to interfaces/source addresses, and you don't need to write specific Python script.

**Edit**

Ah, I may have found the sticky point, and why you think you need NAT.

If you don't just want to "load the switch with traffic", but you want the destination of the traffic to be *the same box* as the source, then you have a problem: There are various safeguards that prevent such a routing loop, and "boomerang" packets. See [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1241712/forcing-ping-to-egress-when-destination-interface-is-local-debian) for details. And yes, NAT can be used to work around this, but there are better ways: It's really easy with namespaces, and having just the destination somewhere else (e.g. in a namespace, or on a different machine connected to the switch) is enough.

Comment: Thank you! Great inputs. Few comments: I could not find a decent example of opening a socket on a namespace'd NIC. I didn't know about socat, but I need to write a python test framework anyway in order to automate test, so socat will end up be 'driven' by Python anyway. FYI ,the second method is nicely presented here: https://serverfault.com/a/309442/461776 And indeed I was having in mind to bind to a specific IP/NIC (in nc, iperf, Python,...) but this does not seem to (force) egress.

Comment: Namespaces are in no way special wrt. to the programming API. Just open the socket as you always do, but make sure you execute the Python program in the namespace (`netns exec ...`).

Comment: IMHO, the method described in the link is completely braindead (though it seems to work, which isn't a contradiction). And one of my pet peeves is ranting about people who use `iptables` instead of proper routing ... and then other people see it and copy it. Don't do that.

Comment: And binding certainly forces egress on a specific NIC, if everything else is setup correctly. That's how e.g. Samba does it if it wants to restrict the interfaces it's working on.

Comment: Thank you so much for your commitment here. I'll try to be more specific too. a.) Actually, it is quite the opposite as I am not willing/trying to run a python script 'inside' the namespace (e.g. netns exec, indeed) but rather trying to 'control/monitor' all 20 nics/namespace _into_ a single Python (and its 20 cli/srvr threads, yes) Probably pyroute2 could help me here, but, again, no decent example found

Comment: b.) Well, in iperf3, the '-B' is meant to force to bind, but still, traffic from one 'binded' IP to the other (both hosted in same box) is performinig at a miraculous 60Gbps (thus loopback/kernel/memory traffic for sure) Could not manage to force the boomerang here. Neither in simple Python, nor netcat, nor... But indeed worked immediately with manual (=outside Python) linux namespaces or  with the 'ugly' NAT trick. So, should I try it with the accept_local/rp_filter flags? or is this part of the third method? Thank you!

Comment: The problem as almost certainly "hosted in the same box". Binding doesn't solve this problem. As I said, there are numerous safeguards and optimizations that prevent routing loops, and for good reasons. Namespaces are IMHO the simplest solution.

Comment: https://github.com/larsks/python-netns is then probably the way to go...so bad it is not an official pip/lib.

Comment: You don't need a Python library for network namespaces, just call `ip netns ...` from Python. Or use a shell script. But if you prefer doing it that way, go ahead ... it doesn't matter which way you do it.

Answer (score 1):

To really load a switch try multicasting!

Using `socat` or `dvblast` to multicast a loop of a small video in very high quality/bandwidth makes for a very good traffic generator, and multicast traffic will always egress.

Comment: Many Thx! I was not considering Multicast actually and thus honnestly did not investigate this (yet). However, I have to check the test cases, but I am afraid I'll have to handle TCP too (and not only UDP) I heard of socat for sniffing serial link but was not considering the tool in my case: will give it a try too ! :)

Comment: For a switch or a NIC there will be no difference between UDP and TCP. That said, you can't use TCP with multicasting, as it is a connection oriented protocol, not a datagramm oriented one. Try describing your TCP test case in the OQ, so we get a better understanding, what you actually need.